# Defining a widget area is breaking my WP site

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

What I would like to do is to create a widget area below my banner.

Here is an example:

[image]

Here are my action Hooks: http://beasomdesign.com/?g_hooks=show

Here is my functions.php page:

```
<?php
//* Start the engine
include_once( get_template_directory() . '/lib/init.php' );

//* Child theme (do not remove)
define( 'CHILD_THEME_NAME', 'Genesis Sample Theme' );
define( 'CHILD_THEME_URL', 'http://www.studiopress.com/' );
define( 'CHILD_THEME_VERSION', '2.0.1' );

//* Enqueue Lato Google font
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'genesis_sample_google_fonts' );
function genesis_sample_google_fonts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'google-font-lato', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,700', array(), CHILD_THEME_VERSION );
}

//* Add HTML5 markup structure
add_theme_support( 'html5' );

//* Add viewport meta tag for mobile browsers
add_theme_support( 'genesis-responsive-viewport' );

//* Add support for custom background
add_theme_support( 'custom-background' );

//* Add support for 3-column footer widgets
add_theme_support( 'genesis-footer-widgets', 3 );

//* Add HTML5 markup structure
add_theme_support( 'html5' );

/** Register widget areas */

genesis_register_sidebar( array(
    'id'                => 'tha',
    'name'          => __( 'Top home Area', 'bd' ),
    'description'   => __( 'This is the top home area for images.', 'bd' ),
) );

genesis_register_sidebar( array(
    'id'                => 'spotlight',
    'name'          => __( ' Middle Content Area', 'bd' ),
    'description'   => __( 'This is the content area for the homepage.', 'bd' ),
) );

/**
 * Add THA widget support for site. If widget not active, don't display
 *
 */

add_action( 'genesis_after_header', 'bd_tha_genesis' );

 function bd_tha_genesis() {

//** If it's the Home page, display tha*/
    if ( is_home() ) {
        genesis_widget_area( 'tha', array(
            'before' => '<div id="tha">',
            'after' => '</div>',
        ) );

    }

}
```

As soon as I add the following code below to my functions.php page my site comes up blank.

```
add_action( 'genesis_before_content', 'bd_spotlight_genesis' );

     function bd_spotlight_genesis() {

    //** If it's the Home page, display spotlight*/
        if ( is_home() ) {
            genesis_widget_area( 'spotlight', array(
                'before' => '<div id="spotlight">',
                'after' => '</div>',
            ) );

        }
```

I don't know php that well but I think my structure might be off. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like you are missing a closing curly brace, on the function declaration, may not be the issue though, could just be copy and paste?

Comment: Looks like I did in fact forget to add the closing curly brace. Well that was an easy fix thank you! :)